# Replacing value in manipulated dataset with previously calculated value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need to manipulate an existing dataframe and create a new one like this:

[image]

I am currently iterating through the x data frame but I am unsure how to get the previously calculated value of y

my code so far :

```py
for i,row in dfarg.iterrows(): 
        for j, column in row.iteritems():
            if j != 'label':
                dfnew.at[i,j] = float(10*(dfnew.at[i,j]-dfnew.shift(-1, axis = 0).at[i,j]))
```

Comment: what is  y here, is it the data frame with same shape as x?

Comment: yes, y will be the new dataframe

Comment: it will have the same shape as x. the first entry of y (y1) will be calculated using y0=0 and the respective values from x , the second entry of y (2) will be calculated using  previously calculated y1 and the respective values from x, and so on..

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

x = pd.DataFrame({'A': [0,1,2,3], 'B':[5,1,2,3]})
y = pd.DataFrame(0, index=x.index, columns=x.columns)

alpha = 0.5
n = 10

for _ in range(n):
    y = (np.array(y) - np.array(x))*alpha

y = pd.DataFrame(y, index=x.index, columns=x.columns)
```

Comment: My x dataframe has shape (809,22). I am unsure if i can approach this the same way.

Comment: Sure, just replace the X matrix with your X matrix, It should work